# Media Center Manual Recording Naming Convention

Tags: windows-media-center, htpc

I am using a program to record a TV show manually with MCE and just noticed that the naming convention on these files is different between machines.  How is the `Manual Recording....wtv` vs `Manual_Recording....wtv` naming convention set, customized, etc.?

The files are being sent to this folder `C:\Users\Public\Recorded TV`